# Inconsistent responses from PowerShell Gallery when retrieving module dependencies

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I'm not entirely sure if this is the right place to post this question but here it goes.

So I'm trying to import PowerShell modules into an Azure Automation account using PowerShell scripts. To do this, I invoke a Rest Method to the PowerShell Gallery and get the module details. Here is a sample of the code.

```
$Url = "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/Search()?`$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=%27$ModuleName%27&targetFramework=%27%27&includePrerelease=false&`$skip=0&`$top=40" 
    $SearchResult = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Url -UseBasicParsing) | Where-Object { $_.properties.title -eq $ModuleName }
    $moduleVersion = $SearchResult.properties.Version
...
$ModuleContentUrl = "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/$ModuleName/$moduleVersion"
...
$Dependencies = $SearchResult.properties.Dependencies
...
$Dependencies | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -and $_.Length -gt 0) {
        $Parts = $_.Split(":")
        $DependencyName = $Parts[0]

        # BELOW LINE CAUSING INCONSISTENCY
        $DependencyVersion = $Parts[1].Trim("[").Trim("]").Split(",")[0]


        # SOME CUSTOM LOGIC HERE
    }
}
```

Now, the inconsistency that I'm seeing is that the dependencies list comes in different way at different times. Below is a sample that i see currently. Note the version numbers coming in batches with both the values having same numbers.

[image]

However, I see that at times, the version number doesn't come like this and comes as a normal string. like below:

```
modulename:moduleversion
```

Why is this inconsistency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PS Gallery follows the NuGet dependency notation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards